# Python: Running function to append values to an empty list returns no values

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

This is probably a very basic question but I haven't been able to figure this out.

I'm currently using the following to append values to an empty list

```
shoes = {'groups':['running','walking']}
df_shoes_group_names = pd.DataFrame(shoes)

shoes_group_name=[]

for type in df_shoes_group_names['groups']:
    shoes_group_name.append(type)

shoes_group_name
['running', 'walking']
```

I'm trying to accomplish the same using a for loop, however, when I execute the loop the list comes back as blank

```
shoes_group_name=[]

def list_builder(dataframe_name):
    if 'shoes' in dataframe_name:
        for type in df_shoes_group_names['groups']:
            shoes_group_name.append(type)

list_builder(df_shoes_group_names)

shoes_group_name
[]
```

Reason for the function is that eventually I'll have multiple DF's with different product's so i'd like to just have if statements within the function to handle the creation of each list

so for example future examples could look like this:

```
df_shoes_group_names
df_boots_group_names
df_sandals_group_names

shoes_group_name=[]
boots_group_name=[]
sandals_group_name=[]


def list_builder(dataframe_name):
    if 'shoes' in dataframe_name:
        for type in df_shoes_group_names['groups']:
            shoes_group_name.append(type)
    elif 'boots' in dataframe_name:
        for type in df_boots_group_names['groups']:
            boots_group_name.append(type)
    elif 'sandals' in dataframe_name:
        for type in df_sandals_group_names['groups']:
            sandals_group_name.append(type)    

list_builder(df_shoes_group_names)
list_builder(df_boots_group_names)
list_builder(df_sandals_group_names)
```

Not sure if I'm approaching this the right way so any advice would be appreciated.

Best,

Comment: Hmm, this should actually work, because you're passing a non-primitive python type as a reference in your function. Maybe there isn't any values in 'group' keys?

Comment: The statement `if 'shoes' in x` evaluates False in your code.  'shoes' is the name of a variable, not the name of one of the dictionary keys.  Calling the function `pd.DataFrames[shoes]` does not cause a string `shoes` to be passed, but a dictionary object that happens to be named 'shoes'.

Comment: You also don't have anything named `'group'` in `shoes`. You _do_ have something named `'groups'`, but that's not the same key. Or, rather, you would, but `pd.DataFrames` is a `NameError`; you probably meant `pd.DataFrame`?

Comment: Made edits to the groups and data frames typo above. The if statement is used to search if the name of the dataframe contains shoes, boots, or sandals and if it does contain either one it’ll append the values in that dataframe to the empty list. In my example about the dataframes for boots and sandals are empty; I listed those as an example of how I would use the code

Comment: You have a function called `function` that takes an argument called `x`! This naming makes no sense. And the function is modifying lists in the global scope, which makes it even less possible to understand what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Edited my question, hopefully easier to understand. Should I be creating the list within the function vs globally if they’ll be referenced further down the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** call or search a variable name as if it were a string.

Instead, use a dictionary to store a variable number of variables.

**Bad practice**

```
# dataframes
df_shoes_group_names = pd.DataFrame(...)
df_boots_group_names = pd.DataFrame(...)
df_sandals_group_names = pd.DataFrame(...)

def foo(x):
    if shoes in df_shoes_group_names:  # <-- THIS WILL NOT WORK
        # do something with x
```

**Good practice**

```
# dataframes
df_shoes_group_names = pd.DataFrame(...)
df_boots_group_names = pd.DataFrame(...)
df_sandals_group_names = pd.DataFrame(...)

dfs = {'shoes': df_shoes_group_names,
       'boots': df_boots_group_names,
       'sandals': df_sandals_group_names}

def foo(key):
    if 'shoes' in key:  # <-- THIS WILL WORK
        # do something with dfs[key]
```